# Is there a way to avoid an empty else { } at the end?

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and try to write a little dice loop. I wonder how to rewrite this in a more appropriate syntax:

```
<?php
    $rollcount = 1;

    do {
        $v = rand(1, 6);
        $w = rand(1, 6);
        $rollcount++;
        echo "<p>$v, $w</p>";
    }
    while ($v != $w);

    if ($v == $w) {
        echo "<p>It took $rollcount turns until double!</p>";
    } else {}
?>
```

Comment: you don't need the else statement if it's empty

Comment: you can simply remove it from here. this will not affect.

Comment: `else ` condition is not mandatory with `if`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rollcount = 0;
while(true){
    ++$rollcount;
    $v = rand(1,6);
    $w = rand(1,6);
    echo "<p>".$v.", ".$w."</p>";
    if($v === $w){
        break;
    }
}
echo "<p>It took ".$rollcount." turns until double!</p>";
```

### Explanation

Since the goal is to achieve a double, the dice can continue rolling till the condition is reached. `while` continues processing until the condition is false, in this case the condition can never be false since we supply the `boolean true` value to the `while(true)` loop. PHP (and many other languages) provide some execution control structures `break, continue` are the most common.

`break` allows you to jump out of a loop and it's possible to execute it when a certain condition is reached within the loop.

`continue` on the other hand doesn't throw you out of the loop rather, it skips to the next iteration of the loop, so what this means is that as soon as `continue` is encountered in a loop, every other statement after it [within the loop] is skipped and the loop moves to the next iteration.

In this case, as soon as we have a double, we **exit** the loop and print out the number of rolls required to reach a double.

Answer (score 2):

just remove `else{}`

```
if ($v == $w) {
   echo "<p>It took $rollcount turns until double!</p>";
}
```

Comment: ...and remove the `if ($v == $w) { }` because the condition will always be true when the condition is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the else. It's that simple.

Comment: ...and remove the pointless `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Your choice to use `do-while()` is appropriate because the `$v` and `$w` values are only declared after the loop is entered.

Because the loop will not finish until the values are identical, you don't need any conditions after the loop.

Your roll count should start from 0 outside of the loop because it is incremented inside of the loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2UlCd))

```
$rollcount = 0;
do {
    $v = rand(1, 6);
    $w = rand(1, 6);
    echo "<p>$v, $w</p>";
    ++$rollcount;
} while ($v !== $w);
echo "<p>Rolls until a double: $rollcount</p>";
```

---

As an academic exercise, this task can be performed using recursion: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DCoXh))

```
function rollsUntilDouble($i = 1)
{
    $v = rand(1, 6);
    $w = rand(1, 6);
    echo "<p>$v, $w</p>";
    return $v === $w ? $i : rollsUntilDouble($i + 1);
}
printf('<p>Rolls until a double: %d</p>', rollsUntilDouble());
```